# RRT algorithm in c++

Tags: algorithm, random, motion-planning

I want to implement RRT for motion planning of a robotic arm. I searched a lot on the internet to get some sample code of RRT for motion planning, but I didn't get any. Can someone please suggest a good source where I can find RRT implemented in C++ for any type of motion planning.

Comment: Try OMPL: http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/classompl_1_1geometric_1_1RRT.html

Comment: thank you for your reply. I will look at it @Yu-HanLyu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic RRT algorithm (with uniform sampling) is simple and not very usefull on its own, that is why you don't see it often implemented as a standalone algorithms in libraries.

Generally every motion planning libraries will also include the RRT implementation as well. My random-tree based optimization library also includes RRT as its base class (which also supports decaying step length and uses KD-tree for nearest neighbor search) [here](https://github.com/ahmadyan/Duplex/blob/master/src/duplex/RRT.cpp).

The other good libraries are [Sertac Karaman's RRT*](https://svn.csail.mit.edu/rrtstar) (also includes RRT and also supports collision detection) and [Kavaraki's implementation](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/classompl_1_1geometric_1_1RRT.html).

If you just want the Vanilla RRT, here is the [classic RRT code from Steve Lavalle](http://msl.cs.illinois.edu/~lavalle/sub/rrt.py) that started all of this.